# Typescript - Programmatic generation of union types from exports

Tags: typescript, types

So, I have a file structure like this:

```
|---- foo.ts
|---- bar.ts
|- index.ts
```

Both `foo.ts` and `bar.ts` export a `Data` interface. What I'd want is to basically create a union type out of the 2 `Data` interfaces exported from `foo` and `bar`. Ideally, this should also be future proof. I.e. if I add a third file at the same level of foo and bar, that file will also export a `Data` interface and that should be included in the union type too.

I was wondering if there was a way of doing this without performing type generation from a JSON schema or something at "compile" time and the programmatic creation of the union type itself from this.

Comment: Are you asking if you can generate the type based purely on the presence of the file, and without importing anything from that explicitly? Because I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Yeah that would kinda be the question. I'm pretty damn doubtful it can be done too, but wanted to be sure since I'm not a Typescript expert.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question:
[Is there a good way to generate types by importing all variables from a file in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130870/is-there-a-good-way-to-generate-types-by-importing-all-variables-from-a-file-in)

I did figure out a way to do this, but it's definitely not pretty:

```js
// index.ts
import * as foo from './foo.ts';
import * as bar from './bar.ts';

const foos = Object.values(foo);
const bars = Object.values(bar);
const foosAndBars = [...foos, ...bars];
export type Foobars = typeof foosAndBars[number];
```